# Changing Images Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4

A simple question about images. I want to display 5 images across a width of a view based on information I am processing.

What control do I use to display the images on iphone and can you please provide a code sample how to set the images source property programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImageView

Either:

```
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"]];
```

Or, if the imageView already exists:

```
myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
```

This would be easiest to do in Interface Builder (create the Image Controls and layout there, then you can set the image property from code).  If you do it in code, you will need to create all 5 of these and then lay them out properly using the frame property of each UIImageView

Documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: The above code is a little misleading, as it is using a class name UIImageView instead of a variable name. But the theory is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use a [UIImageView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to do that. You could add these either programmatically or with Interface Builder. To change the image in the image view, you would do something like:

```
[myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"]];
```

Comment: So if I want 5 different images across the width of the phone, I use 5 UIImageViews correct?